# Input checkboxes in same line as checkbox label

Tags: css, checkbox, layout, alignment, wordpress-theming

I am working with a very complex wordpress them and am trying to customize one area that isn't cooperating.  In a sidebar that is 380px wide, there is a checkbox selector for a search widget that searches locations based on specific offered amenities.  The label for some of these checkboxes are longer than the sidebar is wide and when that happens the text starts on the next line from the checkbox itself where we would prefer it to remain on the same line and wrap from the end.

Here's an image of the current problem:
[image: Sample of current view]

```html
<span class="goption">
<label class="options">
<input type="checkbox" name="field1231091388[]" value="value">
<span class="checkbox">
</span>
</label>
<label for="field1231091388">
Circulation Path (A Continuous And Unobstructed Way Of Travel From Any Point In A Building Or Structure To A Public Way)
</label>
</span>
```

Without resizing the sidebar, how can I ensure that the checkbox stays to the right of the label and breaks at the end of the line rather than at the beginning of the label? Like This:

[goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI7LA.jpg)

Comment: hi, can you post your CSS too?

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the label and the input in a div and set the div to be displayed as flex.

```
<div style="display: flex;">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <label>Lorem lorem em lorem loremLorem lorem lorem Lorem lorem lorem</label>
</div>
```

If this is what you are trying to accomplish

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use bootstrap for easy layout :)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
  <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
    Default checkboxDefault checkboxDefault checkboxDefault checkboxDefault checkboxDefault checkboxDefault checkboxDefault checkboxDefault checkboxDefault checkboxDefault checkboxDefault checkbox
  </label>
</div>
<div class="form-check">
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck2" disabled>
  <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck2">
    Disabled checkbox
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: This would work well if it weren't for the wordpress dashboard theme backend automating the build of the checkbox code (poorly) and the end user's desire to keep the backend intact for ease of use purposes which is why we are trying to stick to css to correct the issue.

Comment: Loading an entire library is not a good idea for such a simple problem.